# Maui .net Making a login and signup page

Tags: c#, mongodb, maui

I tried to make an application using Maui.net for my school project, but when I sign up and click the signup button, it says that [DOTNET] Error during admin insertion: The list of configured name servers must not be empty. (Parameter 'servers')

this is my DBConnection class

```
public class DBConnection
    {
        private IMongoDatabase _database;

        public DBConnection()
        {
            try
            {
               
                var mongoClient = new MongoClient("mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.4jhaesp.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

                _database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("homefinder");
                Console.WriteLine("Connection to the database is successful.");
            }
            catch (MongoException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error during database connection: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Unexpected error during database connection: {ex}");
                throw;
            }
        }

        public IMongoDatabase GetDatabase()
        {
            if (_database == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Database is not initialized. Make sure DBConnection constructor is called successfully.");
            }

            return _database;
        }
    }
```

this is my SignupViewModel

```
public class Admins
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string Role { get;set; }
    }

public class SignupViewModel : BindableObject
    {
        private string _fullname;
        private string _username;
        private string _password;
        private string _selectedRole;

        public string Fullname
        {
            get => _fullname;
            set
            {
                _fullname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Fullname));
            }
        }

        public string Username
        {
            get => _username;
            set
            {
                _username = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Username));
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get => _password;
            set
            {
                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Password));
            }
        }

        public string SelectedRole
        {
            get => _selectedRole;
            set
            {
                _selectedRole = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedRole));
            }
        }

        private async Task Signup(string password)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Fullname) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please fill in all required fields.");
                    return;
                }

                var hashedPassword = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.HashPassword(Password);

                var admin = new Admins
                {
                    Fullname = Fullname,
                    Username = Username,
                    PasswordHash = hashedPassword,
                    Role = SelectedRole
                };

                await InsertAdminAsync(admin);

                await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error during signup: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        private async Task InsertAdminAsync(Admins admin)
        {
            try
            {
                var dbConnection = new DBConnection();
                var database = dbConnection.GetDatabase();
                var adminsCollection = database.GetCollection<Admins>("admins");

                await adminsCollection.InsertOneAsync(admin);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error during admin insertion: {ex.Message}");
            }
            
        }
        

    public Command<string> SignupCommand => new Command<string>(async (password) => await Signup(password));
    }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:homefinderpro.ViewModels"
             x:Class="homefinderpro.Page.SignupPage"
             Title="SignupPage">

    


    <StackLayout Background="#4F59DE" Padding="30">
        <Label Text="SIGN UP" 
               TextColor="White" FontFamily="Poppins-Bold" FontSize="30"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        <Frame BackgroundColor="White" Padding="20" CornerRadius="10">
            <StackLayout>
                <Entry x:Name="FullnameEntry" Placeholder="Full Name" Text="{Binding Fullname}" />
                <Entry x:Name="UsernameEntry" Placeholder="Username" Text="{Binding Username}" />
                <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True" Text="{Binding Password}"/>

                <Picker x:Name="RolePicker" Title="Select Role" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRole, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        
                <Button Text="SIGN UP"
                        Background="Orange" TextColor="White"
                        Command="{Binding SignupCommand}"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>

        <Button Text="Already have an account? Login"
                BackgroundColor="Orange" TextColor="White"
                Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I try to connected to my local mongodb compass and atlas but the error still the same. I would like that when I create an account it will be saved in my database mongodb

Comment: What type of authentication do you want (active or passive)?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/billing#mau-overview

Comment: which specific line throws the exception?